# How to parse HTTP headers using sscanf

Tags: c

I want to parse string, like a HTTP header, something like this:

> *"Header: some_data\r\nHost: domain.net\r\nConnection: Keep-alive\r\n"*.

For example, I tried to get a value of Host header

and used this call:

> sscanf(data, "Host: %s\r\n", name)),
>   but sscanf returns a 0 retval.

Code example:

```
char name[255] = { 0 };
const char str[] = "Header: some_data\r\nHost: domain.net\r\nConnection: Keep-alive\r\n";

sscanf(str, "Host: %s\r\n", name);
```

I expected, that it should returns a *"domain.net"* in name variable.
What is a better way to do this, using **only** *sscanf()* function?

Comment: what is your complete code? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I'm not sure sscanf will search for 'Host' in your input string. It may just see that 'Host' doesn't match the start of the string and then abort.

Comment: `sscanf` is a poor choice for parsing. Parsing is not the purpose of `scanf`.

Comment: "*How to parse HTTP headers using sscanf*", a.k.a. How to get huge security holes in your web server, nicely exploitable over the internet.